# SQL Server developing Random Points inside of a Zip code off of a center point

Tags: sql-server, random, gis, geography, trigonometry

I am trying to get SQL Server to generate random points for each Zip code, for each LocationID. So I have added the center point for each Zip code, and would like to distribute these points around the center point. For each locationID I would like a point. Here is what my table looks like currently.

Table name= Location

```
LocationName; varchar
locationID; int
ZIP: int
CentroidLat;float
CentroidLng;float
```

Sample data:

```
LocationName         LocationID      Zip      CentriodLat    CentroidLNG 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    JV                    1         99999      38.999999      - 93.999999
    JV                    2         99999      38.999999      - 93.999999
    AA                    1         11111      37.999999      - 94.999999
    AA                    2         11111      37.999999      - 94.999999
    AA                    3         11111      37.999999      - 94.999999
    BB                    1         22222      36.999999      - 95.999999
    BB                    2         22222      36.999999      - 95.999999
```

So for each zip's LocationId I would like a random lat long within the Zip Code. I could get this in a square or circle that would work fine. It does not need to be too exact. Also each Zip Code is going to be a different size so if there could be a variable that i could change manually in the code that would be great!

This is what I would like it to look like

```
`LocationName    LocationID    Zip    CentroidLat      Centroid      RandLat   RandLNG`

    JV              1        99999      38.999999    - 93.999999    -93.7436  -94.0124  
    JV              2        99999      38.999999    - 93.999999    -93.9653  -94.0052 
    AA              1        11111      37.999999    - 94.999999    110.9636  -95.7219   
    AA              2        11111      37.999999    - 94.999999    102.6538  -95.7489
    AA              3        11111      37.999999    - 94.999999    101.9887  -96.0089
    BB              1        22222      36.999999    - 95.999999    137.5311  -97.9698  
    BB              2        22222      36.999999    - 95.999999    46.7497   -96.9266
```

Is this possible?

I found this... [SQL Server generating random spatial geography around point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953152/sql-server-generating-random-spatial-geography-around-point?answertab=active#tab-top)
but cannot get it to work.

I keep getting this error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Errors happen when I try and insert my table name and column into the top of the code.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is a generic SQL error which has nothing to do with spatial/geographic objects. In the code referenced by your link, I've created a table variable to hold some sample values and set it up so that multiple values will be returned for the zip code 98765. Running the code, you will get the error you describe:

```
DECLARE @geo      AS GEOGRAPHY
        , @newgeo AS GEOGRAPHY
DECLARE @ZipCodes AS TABLE
  (
       [ZipGeo]    GEOGRAPHY
       , [ZipCode] SYSNAME
  );

INSERT INTO @ZipCodes
            ([ZipGeo]
             , [ZipCode])
VALUES      (geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656 )', 4326),N'98765'),
            (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-122.358 47.653 , -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326),N'98765');

SET @geo = (SELECT [ZipGeo]
            FROM   @ZipCodes
            WHERE  [ZipCode] = '98765')
```

The way to address this is either to "SELECT TOP(1) .... ORDER BY ..." as below, but the ORDER BY is really not used here and you can't sort by the GEOGRAPHY type.

```
DECLARE @geo      AS GEOGRAPHY
        , @newgeo AS GEOGRAPHY
DECLARE @ZipCodes AS TABLE
  (
       [ZipGeo]    GEOGRAPHY
       , [ZipCode] SYSNAME
  );

INSERT INTO @ZipCodes
            ([ZipGeo]
             , [ZipCode])
VALUES      (geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656 )', 4326),N'98765'),
            (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-122.358 47.653 , -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326),N'98765');

SET @geo = (SELECT TOP(1) [ZipGeo]
            FROM   @ZipCodes
            WHERE  [ZipCode] = '98765'
            ORDER  BY [ZipCode])
```

Alternately you can do this, but this is really bad practice.

```
DECLARE @geo      AS GEOGRAPHY
        , @newgeo AS GEOGRAPHY
DECLARE @ZipCodes AS TABLE
  (
       [ZipGeo]    GEOGRAPHY
       , [ZipCode] SYSNAME
  );

INSERT INTO @ZipCodes
            ([ZipGeo]
             , [ZipCode])
VALUES      (geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656 )', 4326),N'98765'),
            (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-122.358 47.653 , -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326),N'98765');

SELECT @geo = [ZipGeo]
FROM   @ZipCodes
WHERE  [ZipCode] = '98765';
```

It is preferable to have a column you can order by and return just the top(1) for the set. That way your SQL statement is deterministic. Since SQL does NOT guarantee an order, you have to order your results to guarantee a return.

Regardless, this is the cause of the error you are seeing. There are several ways to address it. This is a common error I see in production code where people assume the data will always be "good" and will return only one value. Then, when the data returns multiple values (as in your case or my example) the code fails and people wonder why.

The best practice is to write the code defensively and decoratively such that you state exactly what you desire to get.